Solving integral that includes exponential and logarithmic terms
I am trying to solve the integral
$$y = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}x \: \log \left( x^2 + 1 \right) \exp \left( -a x^2 - b x \right)$$
for positive, real $a$ and $b$. I've tried substitutions, integration by parts, differentiation under the integral sign, and looked at solving it via contour integration, but nothing has stuck. Does anyone have intuition as to how it could be solved?
Many thanks in advanced!

Just an idea: with a change of variable, you can write $y$ as the Weierstrass transform of some function (convolution with a Gaussian function) at a certain point. Maybe someone already tried to compute it.

Thank you @YvesDaoust, I've updated the question for clarity. I should have specified that the function is only interesting near and around the origin for the relevant $a$ and $b$, meaning $x^2 \gg 1$ is not a useful approximation.

Thanks for the suggestion @Kolakoski54, I'll have a look.

If $c < 1$, you can replace the logarithm by its Taylor series.

@YvesDaoust I'm not sure I understand you. I am non insisting that $x^2 \gg 1$ (if I was, $\log \left( x^2 + 1 \right) \approx \log \left( x^2 \right)$ and the integral gives a ${}_2F_2$ hypergeometric function). I was just trying to avoid answers using that approach.

Sorry @YvesDaoust that you think I'm spoiling my question. I've removed the assumption.

Yes, if only it was $\log \left( x^2 \right)$, but alas!

For certain ranges of values of $a$ and $b$, this integral can be well-approximated via a form of Laplace's method.
